# Elastic DIV with 100% Height - (Header Height + Footer Height)

Tags: html, css

How to design content DIV to elastic, like 100% Height - (Header Height + Footer Height)?

I tried the following coding, it works 99% as I expected in small content. But, it fails in large contents.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#header
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#content
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
    height: calc(100vh - 140px);
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    color: black;
}
#space
{
    padding: 30px;
}
#footer
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">Header Title</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="space">
Content
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer Title</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use `min-height: calc(100vh - 140px); height: calc(100vh - 140px);` it looks better in small content. But, shows small y-axis scroll.

[image: Elastic Height]

Comment: What should happen when content exceed page height? .. Push footer down or start scroll content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update of your code sample, which stays 100% high and then grows with content.

What I did was adding `box-sizing: border-box` so your header/footer borders gets calculated within the height, or you could change the content width to `min-height: calc(100% - 144px);`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#header
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    line-height: 98px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content
{
    text-align: justify;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
    color: black;
}
#space
{
    padding: 30px;
}
#footer
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
    line-height: 38px;
    color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">Header Title</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="space">
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
      Content <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine. But, while pressing **F11** key (full screen) its shows a small white border at the bottom of the footer in IE and FF (_not in Chrome_). Can it be solved?

Comment: @ak-SE Updated my answer. The `line-height` was causing that.

Comment: Now works fine in FF & Chrome. Still IE shows very small white border at the bottom.

Comment: @ak-SE I checked my IE11/Edge, works great. Did you refresh page? .. What IE version do you use?

Comment: I use IE 11 and Edge. In IE 11 the border is very very small. Edge does not support **F11**.
Is this due to any background plugins in the browser??

Comment: @ak-SE I don't use any plugins so can't say. Does IE11 show the scrollbar? ... And if so, what if you increase the px in `min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);` to like 150px or more, does it still show scroll and/or bottom white space?

Comment: I tried `min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);` and `min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);`. Still shows the same. I have attached the link of the snapshot. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/M8maoYP.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101659/discussion-between-lgson-and-ak-se).